# Google apps script doGet not being run?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is driving me crazy. I have following code in my doGet function:

```js
function doGet() {
  Logger.log(CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CALENDAR_ID));
  //CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CALENDAR_ID)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("dfgfgfd");
}
```

I do publish the app with the new version (done it maybe 6 six times by now). I open the app using the URL (tried both dev and exec) in the browser and it returns "The script completed but did not return anything."
How could it not return anything if there's a clear return statement in the `doGet`. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: If you delete (delete, not comment out) those two CalendarApp lines, does it work?

Comment: Consider using `console.log` and viewing your logs with Stackdriver

Comment: How about redeploying Web Apps as a new version? Because I thought that the latest script might be not reflected to Web Apps. At that time, please confirm ``CALENDAR_ID``. If ``CALENDAR_ID`` is declared as a global variable, when you access to Web Apps using your browser, ``dfgfgfd`` is displayed. If ``CALENDAR_ID`` is not declared, the error message is displayed instead of ``The script completed but did not return anything.``. If this was not the solution, I'm sorry.

Comment: I agree with @Tanaike , try redeploying as a new version. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R71oo-5NmPE&list=PL68F511F6E3C122EB) might provide you some more inputs if needed.

Comment: Guys, did you read my post: I did redeploy (maybe 6 times). It doesn't help.

Comment: @Diego. Nope. Same result.

Comment: @tehhowch No logs there either.

Comment: @elena, do you have only one .gs file with the function doGet() in your project?

Comment: @edward yes! It's super strange that it just doesn't do what I want.

Comment: @elena, for me it works fine, maybe content was just cashed in the browser and that is the reason. Did you try to clear cash or test it in different browser?

Comment: @edward I use incognito windows. But I will try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @elena : I read your post but I wanted to highlight the new version part, which now you have updated in the question. It is working for me as well. Just to be clear you have reviewed and granted the permissions as well right?

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi Yes, I have. In the end I just created a new project and still haven't figured out why it didn't work.